# have no permission to access superset tables either from load_examples or added manually after installation

Tags: apache-superset

i have airbnb superset setup on centos 6.6 and python 3.4 virtual env. the web server is booted up without error logged and also OK to browse the web ui. but neither the tables which are already there due to"superset load_examples" in setupup, nor the mysql tables i managed to add in web ui by myself, are accessable from web ui. all tables are reported "The endpoint requires the datasource tablenamexxx, database or 'all datasource_access' permission", "You do not have permission to access the datasource(s):multiformat_time_series."

Anyone familiar with superset can help check this?

Error prompt is like this pic:
[image: no permission error pic]

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered this issue myself by neglecting to run the `superset init` command during the [installation and initialization process](https://superset.apache.org/installation.html#superset-installation-and-initialization) before starting the webserver. Shutting down the webserver, running `superset init`, then restarting the webserver with `superset runserver` solved the issue for me.